# addEventListener will not attach to element

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onsubmit

I'm attempting to set an event listener to a submit button.  Using console.log and chrome's webtools, I can verify that the 'submitButton' element is not null at the time of calling `addEventListener`, and properly references the DOM element.  I can also verify that processLogin is not null (returns as a function).  The processLogin function does not appear to even fire (I never get the alert, and the page refreshes, so `event.preventDefault` isn't working), I don't believe that `addEventListener` is attaching the function in the first place.

Below is my code

```
//variables
var usernameField = document.getElementById('loginField_username_textbox');
var passwordField = document.getElementById('loginField_password_textbox');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('loginButton');

//event listeners
submitButton.addEventListener('submit', processLogin);
console.log(submitButton,processLogin);

//functions
function processLogin(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Username: ' + usernameField.value + ', Password: ' + passwordField.value);
}
```

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was under the impression that the submit button also fires a `submit` event?  However even when I set the event listener to the form element nothing happens.

Comment: @Isaac it does fire a `submit` event, but on the form, not the button itself

Comment: @CertainPerformance It actually appears that *did* solve the problem.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "submit" button's click inside a `form` will fire the *button*'s `click` event, and then the *form*'s `submit` event will fire. A button will not have a `submit` event fired on it. So you'll either have to `preventDefault` on the button's click event:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log('default prevented');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

or on the form's `submit` event:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  console.log('default prevented');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This appears to have fixed the problem.  I will accept the answer as soon as possible.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```
<form onsubmit="myListener()">
  <input type="text" id="loginField_username_textbox" placeholder="email" />
  <input type="text" id="loginField_password_textbox" placeholder="password" />
  <button id="loginButton">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

#### Javascript

```
function myListener() {
  alert('Username: ' + usernameField.value + ', Password: ' + passwordField.value)
}
```